# Windows 10 Universal Helloworld app XAML designer not loading

Tags: visual-studio-2015, windows-10, win-universal-app

I installed widnoews 10 Visual studio 2015 and enabled developer account from settings and created a  empty Universal app and nothing i added as my own . 
When i try to build the code it shows the error

Error       Build action 'Page' is not supported by the specific combination of the project's targets.  HelloWorldWin10 C:\LabWork Codes\HelloWorldWin10\HelloWorldWin10\MainPage.xaml  0

Is anything wrong in installation or do need to enable more something different 
Screenshot is also attached here

[image]

And there is one more error

[image]

Now what i did is Unlinked my microsoft account and restart machine reopen Visual studio now build error disappeared but my xaml designer is now not loading

[image]

Comment: try clean the solution and rebuild.

Comment: @Joseph No luck with cleaning and rebuilding

Comment: did you tried deploying the App to an emulator or local machine?

Comment: @Joseph No i have'nt did that [ BTWN Please see the  edit in question] Now no more build error , but xaml designer error

Comment: close the page and open it again i hope it will re-load.By the way now are you able to run the app?

Comment: Yes now i can run app and can see xaml designer . Please see my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Delete platform Environment variable helps to fix my problems

Here is one link explains similar issue

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/78c6c95c-c85a-4c6f-98a9-a1a4f334d5ef/designer-and-blend-fail-to-load-vs2015-community-on-win10?forum=vssetup

Answer (score 0):

Can you generate diagnostic build output for your project and share it? I can take a quick look on which component in the build pipeline is failing.

You can generate diagnostic output by going to Tools --> Options --> Project and Solutions --> Build and run and setting MSBuild project build output verbosity and build log file verbosity to "Diagnostic".

Once done, rebuild the project and copy the log from the output window.

If you can upload the log on a public shared location (ex: OneDrive), I can take a look.

Comment: Unlinked my microsoft account and restart machine reopen Visual studio now build error disappeared but my xaml designer is now not loading see edit in question and attachement